# Error: Config validation error: "JWT_SECRET" is required. "JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME" is required. What is this. How to avoid this

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, docker-compose, configuration

I have `docker-compose.yml`like following

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-server:
    build: ./api_test
    links:
      - 'db'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./api:/src
      - ./src/node_modules
    tty: true
    container_name: api-server

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    volumes:
      - './db:/config'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    container_name: db
```

I `build`them and `up`

When I tried to enter its `container`

`docker exec -it api-server sh`

and

`npm start`

`Error: Config validation error: "JWT_SECRET" is required. "JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME" is required.`

What is `JWT_SECRET`?
And How to avoid this?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use [`jsonwebtoken`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) or anything similar anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes,I guess I must set JWT_SECRET and JWT_EXPIRATION in `.env` file. But as I am novice, I couldnt figure out how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

I persume that u have a .env file containing env variables like 'JWT_SECRET' and 'JWT_EXPIRY' and in some way the .env file is not being used to docker compose. (Most probably, u have .env in .dockerignore and its really a good practice). So we need a way to send the .env file or env variables to docker compose. To do this, ADD the following to the DOCKERFILE:

```
RUN echo JWT_EXPIRY=$JWT_EXPIRY \n\
JWT_SECRET=$JWT_SECRET >> ./.env
```

and the way the docker-compose cmd changes is

```
docker-compose build --build-arg JWT_EXPIRY="your expiry" --build-arg JWT_SECRET = "your secret"
```

What we are doing is basically we are writing a new .env file with values that we send as build arguments during docker compose build.